# Drupal 9 - How to pass view data to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, drupal-9

I have a custom module with a view that lists some data from a web service and has some filters in it (date, numeric, combos, etc).
I need to modify some filters when others change their value. For example, When the user changes the date, I have to change the selected value of a combo box.
I was trying to pass the filter values to a javascript file, but I couldn't find a way yet.
I tried using the "page_attachments" hook and a controller but none of them work.

Can somebody point me in the right direction on how I can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you add a class via form_alter hook and then catch it with jquery? WIth Jquery you can then use .change()

Comment: Yes, I thought I had to pass the filter values through a controller. I'll try your approach. Thank you very much.